# How to make a div fill remaining space?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a web page with a header, content and footer.

There is a background image in the content.  I would like the image to fill the remaining space between the header and footer.  There are divs that are children of the content div with the image that will sometimes have content and other times will not.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id='main'>
    <div id='header'>
        <div id='logoCompany'>
            <img class='headerGraphics' src='Graphics\logo smaller.jpg'><img class='headerGraphics' src='Graphics\Marvelous Header3 small.png'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='contentParent' class='floatClear'>
        <div id='content' style = "text-align: center;">
            <div id='leftPane'>
                Left Col
            </div>  
            <div id='rightPane'>
                Right Col
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='footer'>
    Footer      
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
}
.floatClear {
    clear: both;
}

.headerGraphics {
    display: inline;
}

#header { 
    background: #023489;
    text-align: center;
}

#logoCompany {
    display: inline;
}
#contentParent {    
    height: 373px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../Graphics/background.jpg);
 } 
#leftPane { 
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
    margin: 100px 0 0 10%;
    opacity: .5;
    width:40%; 
}    
#rightPane { 
    background: green;
    float: right;
    margin: 100px 10% 0 0;
    opacity: .5;
    width:40%; 
}
#footer { 
    width:100%; 
}
```

I tried height: 100% but I suspect this fails without content.  In fact I think that's why everything fails except when I hard code a height.  But that is not a good solution for obvious reasons.

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/6pm6yzeo/)

Anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

EDIT:
I tried changing this:

```
#contentParent {    
    height: 373px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../Graphics/background.jpg);
 }
```

to this:

```
#contentParent {    
    flex: 1;
    background-image: url(../Graphics/background.jpg);
 }
```

But it shrunk the div to the size of the child div, making things worse..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which defines header, footer and `#contentParent` as `position: fixed` and gives `#contentParent` 100% height minus the height of header and footer (= 80px in this example - this depends on your own settings).

Any additional content has to be added inside `#contentParent` - this element will then scroll since it has `overflow-y:auto;`. The header and footer will always remain on the screen due to their absolute position and won't cover any part of the content since `#contentParent` has according margins at top and bottom which equal the height of the header and footer.

The background image will `cover` `#contentParent` completely and won't scroll diue to `background-attachment: fixed` (integrated in the shortcut `background` property)

```css
html,
body,
#main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.floatClear {
  clear: both;
}

.headerGraphics {
  display: inline;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #023489;
  text-align: center;
}

#logoCompany {
  display: inline;
}

#contentParent {
  position: fixed;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  width: 100%;
  overflow-Y: auto;
  margin: 40px 0;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/1500x800/fc7) center center no-repeat;
  background-position: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

#leftPane {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
  margin: 100px 0 0 10%;
  opacity: .5;
  width: 40%;
}

#rightPane {
  background: green;
  float: right;
  margin: 100px 10% 0 0;
  opacity: .5;
  width: 40%;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='main'>
    <div id='header'>
      <div id='logoCompany'>
        <img class='headerGraphics' src='Graphics\logo smaller.jpg'><img class='headerGraphics' src='Graphics\Marvelous Header3 small.png'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='contentParent' class='floatClear'>
      <div id='content' style="text-align: center;">
        <div id='leftPane'>
          Left Col
        </div>
        <div id='rightPane'>
          Right Col
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='footer'>
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using flexbox,

here is a simplified version from your code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh
}

#header,
#footer {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contentParent {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:100%
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='header'>
    <div id='logoCompany'>
      Logo Name
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='contentParent'>
    <div id='content'>
      <div id='leftPane'>
        Left Col
      </div>
      <div id='rightPane'>
        Right Col
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='footer'>
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you want to display stretch the image over the whole screen you can use the css tag:

```
background-size: cover;
```

You can read more here about the [css tag](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: Already tried that.  I tried it again and it fails to increase the size of the div.